# Laravel Routes don't return datas, only return View SPA

Tags: vue.js, routes, single-page-application, laravel-5.8

Laravel 5.8 only return the view of SPA for any route.

Iam building a crud with Laravel 5.8 + vue and I want to define 2 routes in routes/web.php 
the first route return SPA vue app
the second instead it returns a collection of new App\User instances.

When I try call crud.test/users laravel return SPA crud again and the second route never execute.

But If I remove the first route crud.test/users works.

```
Route::get('{path}', function () {
  return view('spa');
})->where('path', '(.*)');


Route::get('/users', function () {
  return factory('App\User', 10)->make();
});
```

I expect to laravel returnme array of 10 Users

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a wild card : `{path}` to catch all requests in the first route!

try to put the `/users` route first:

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
  return factory('App\User', 10)->make();
});

Route::get('{path}', function () {
  return view('spa');
})->where('path', '(.*)');
```